# My Window is Forced to Maximized on Java Applet/JFrame

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, awt

I've tried running both an Applet and a JFrame following certain YouTube tutorials, but when they run on my computer, they ignore the size I specify for the window, and forcibly open maximized and will simply not resize.

Here's a simple example Applet I ran:

```
package pong;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Pong extends Applet{
    final int WIDTH = 700, HEIGHT = 500;

    public void init() {
        this.resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
    }
}
```

I cannot resize the window/panel. I don't know if this is an issue with my computer Yoga 2 Pro.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I think perhaps I wasn't clear enough. I am simply not managing to correctly view ANY JPanel or Applet. They display on my Yoga 2 Pro as maximized, and with their content being strange as well. In this example I'm simply trying to get a 700x500 window, but Java ignores this fact on my computer.
Thanks

Comment: The code is working fine. I mean to say the `resize()` method works fine. Also you can use `setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)` to set the size of applet instead of `resize()`.

Comment: When do you need the window to resize?

Comment: `this.resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);`  Don't attempt this in an applet.  The applet is typically a guest in a web page, and its size is set by the HTML.  A good time to get used to that is when developing the applet.  As an aside:  Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).